# Problem retraing PPO1 model and using Ternsorflow with SB2

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am new at **stable baselines and RL**. What I am trying to do is :

1. loading my previously trained model from my computer and then re-train it from the point it ended it’s last training. For that, I am loading my previously saved model inside  policy_fn() and I am giving policy_fn as parameter inside pposgd_simple.learn() method. It shows error "***ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: pi/obfilter/count***"

Also, I am unsure of whether it starts the training from the previous ending point or whether it started the training from the very beginning (when it trains correctly in a different setting). Can anyone please help me directing the way to verify it. One option may be printing the model parameters, but I am unsure of it.

2. I am also trying to use Tensorboard to monitor my training. But when I run the training, the program says “tensorboard_log=logger_path, TypeError: learn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tensorboard_log'. ” My stable baselines version 2.10.2. I am attaching my entire code of training below.

```
def make_env(seed=None):
reward_scale = 1.0

rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
myseed = seed + 1000 * rank if seed is not None else None
set_global_seeds(myseed)
env = Env()


env = Monitor(env, logger_path, allow_early_resets=True)

env.seed(seed)
if reward_scale != 1.0:
from baselines.common.retro_wrappers import RewardScaler

env = RewardScaler(env, reward_scale)
return env


def train(num_timesteps, path=None):

from baselines.ppo1 import mlp_policy, pposgd_simple

sess = U.make_session(num_cpu=1)
sess.__enter__()

def policy_fn(name, ob_space, ac_space):
    policy = mlp_policy.MlpPolicy(name=name, ob_space=ob_space, ac_space=ac_space,
            hid_size=64, num_hid_layers=3)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    if path is not None:
        print("Tried to restore from ", path)
        U.initialize()
        saver.restore(tf.get_default_session(), path)
        saver2 = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/srcs/src/models/model1.meta')
        model = saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/srcs/src/models/'))
        #return policy
        return saver2

env = make_env()


pi = pposgd_simple.learn(env, policy_fn,
max_timesteps=num_timesteps,
timesteps_per_actorbatch=1024,
clip_param=0.2, entcoeff=0.0,
optim_epochs=10,
optim_stepsize=5e-5,
optim_batchsize=64,
gamma=0.99,
lam=0.95,
schedule='linear',
tensorboard_log=logger_path,
#tensorboard_log="./ppo1_tensorboard/",
)
env.env.plotSave()
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
saver.save(sess, '/models/model1') 
return pi


def main():
logger.configure()
path_ = "/models/model1" 
train(num_timesteps=409600, path=path_) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
logger_path = None if logger.get_dir() is None else os.path.join(logger.get_dir(), str(rank))
main()
```